# Continue Makefile after user pressed Ctrl-C

Tags: make

I'm using `make` to run a development webserver (among other things). After the server quits, I want to perform some cleanup task. The server is exited after I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but this causes `make` to stop any further execution of commands. As a simple example Makefile I provide the following:

```
default:
    sleep 10
    echo hello
```

When I call `make` and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> before the time is up, I don't see "hello". What I've tried (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670130/make-how-to-continue-after-a-command-fails)):

- Running make with `-i`, `-k`, or both
- Changing the second entry to `-sleep 10` or `sleep 10 | true`

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer over on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32788564/1016216): Split the command in two, and trap SIGINT in the "outer" one:

```
external-target:
    bash -c "trap 'trap - SIGINT SIGTERM ERR; echo hello; exit 1' SIGINT SIGTERM ERR; $(MAKE) internal-target"

internal-target:
    sleep 10
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with GNU Make 4.1. I still get `Makefile:5: recipe for target 'internal-target' failed` and `make: *** [internal-target] Interrupt`.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen I don't have a system with Make 4.1 available; I confirmed that this still works with GNU Make 3.81. So it doesn't print the "hello" anymore after you ^C?

Comment: It does say "hello" but if you add an another command to `external-target` after the line starting with `bash` (e.g. `echo "Complete."`) you'll find that `make` still aborts with `make[1]: *** [internal-target] Interrupt`. However, I did find a way to make this work, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65935205/334451 for details.